# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') React APP

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, package.json

I'm getting this error in my React APP:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/tatup/Desktop/GrowApp/frontend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
View compiled
./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
```

This is how I import Express to my server.js file:

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Fixed. I had a import {response} from 'express' random. I think that it was GH Copilot fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
const http = require('http');

const res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
```